# for and while on javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've just started learning JavaScript. I have to create the multiplication table of 7 , I tried this code:

```js
const nombre = 7; 

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 console.log( i x nombre = i * nombre); 
}
```

I want this result:

```
1 x 7 =7 
2 x 7 =14 ...
```

Comment: You have to put the i x nombre = in quotes and add a , after the first i and after the =

Comment: That should be part of every tutorial on JavaScript: [Handling text — strings in JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings)

Comment: @retake This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code also without **Template Literals**

```
var nombre = 7;
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    total = i * nombre;
    console.log(i + ' x ' + nombre + ' = ' + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): As from Docs:

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.

```js
const number = 7; 
    
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(`${i} x ${number} = ${i * number}`); 
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const nombre = 7; 

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 console.log( `${i} x ${nombre} = ${i * nombre}`); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **while()** method you can create a function and pass the number of times you want the multiplication to occur, in your example 10.

```
const nombre = 7

const results = num => {
    let count = 0;
    while (num >= count) {
        count++
        console.log(count*7); // 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77
    }
}

results(10);
```